# Connecting to remote server with bad interpreter

Tags: ssh

I have a remote server that I connect to via ssh. But I changed the default shell to fish and uninstalled... Now when I try to connect to the server it disconnects after giving the the error:

```
/bin/bash: /tmp/tmp.E3YgHOku6d: /usr/bin/fish: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Now I don't have access to the server's shell. How do I fix this error so that I can reconnect?

Comment: Unless you have another, working,  userid set up on the remote server, or have a trusted person at the remote server, you cannot.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"the default shell"*? It looks like your remote user still has a valid login shell (/bin/bash). Is there something inside your ~/.profile / or ~/.bash_login that is subsequently trying to run a fish shell script?

Comment: @steeldriver I used chsh

Comment: @waltinator What commands should I have the other user run to fix this? Preferably I would want to reset the shell to bash.